# tmux: update enviroment for bash function

Tags: bash, tmux

I need to export bash function to be used as in example below. Note that the body of functions in my example
is simplified. In real case is more complicated. I do not want to write whole
bodies of function in *send-keys* arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

TMUX_SESSION="experiment"                       
LOG_FILENAME="_log"                                   

exec_commad() { 
   run_my_commad_that_produces_log_messages > $LOG_FILENAME
}  

watch_errors() { 
   tail -F ${LOG_FILENAME} | grep -E ' (WARNING|ERROR|CRITICAL) ' 
} 

tmux new-session -d -s "$TMUX_SESSION"
tmux send-keys "exec_commad" 'C-m'                                                                              
tmux split-window -v                                                         
tmux send-keys "watch_errors" 'C-m'               

tmux -2 att -t $TMUX_SESSION
```

Idea is to make

```
set-option -ga update-environment ' exec_commad watch_errors'
```

works also with function not only with variables.

Comment: Functions aren't part of the environment unfortunately. I've never used tmux, so I don't know if there's a better way, but might I suggest simply putting your commands in separate scripts, and simply call those script-files?

Comment: @roe Yes, but my example is very simplified. I have more function than just two (for more tmux window) - and which is more - whole script is generated for just singe usage. Storing functions in separate files complicates the problem (ex: when to delete these temporaty files?). For more clarification: my target is to make a tool to run command with self-monitoring (duration, analyze log files, cpu/memory, ...) under tmux.

Comment: You may need to explicitly export the functions first with `export -f exec_command watch_errors`. `bash` essentially crams the function definition into a single string of the form `() = { ... }` and assigns it to a variable with the same name as the function. Other `bash` shells can reconstruct functions from such environment "variables".

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to define your functions in a file and source the file in the tmux session with `send_keys`

```
tmux send-keys -t<whatever>:<pane> ". <path to function definitions>" C-m
```